# Initializing an array in C not working

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill a 12x12 board, stored in a 2D array, with the '.' character.

```
void initializeBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]) {
   int i, j;
   for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
         board[i][j] = '.';
      }
   }
}
```

and then to print:

```
void printBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]) {

   int i,j;

   for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
         printf(" %c", board[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");

}
```

It prints out an empty grid. Doesn't look like anything is being stored in the board[][]. Help please?

Comment: how u allocate board array and how to call initializeBoard and printBoard. Show code of them.

Comment: Worked for me!  No errors in this code.  Show the code with the error in it.

Comment: It appears that you're declaring two separate board[] arrays instead of one, which would explain how the one you assign values to doesn't match the one you're printing out.

Comment: These methods are fine, can you edit the question and provide the code where you initialise the array and then call these two functions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing everything fine, at least within the code snippets you've shown.  When I run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOARD_SIZE 12

void initializeBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]);
void printBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]);

int main() {
    char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    initializeBoard(board);
    printBoard(board);
    return 0;
}

void initializeBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            printf(" %c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.exe
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

You must somehow/somewhere be declaring a second board and passing that in to your `printBoard()` function.  Can you show us more code, please?

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel like an idiot now. I forgot to call the initializeBoard function... Can't believe I've been stuck on this for hours. Thanks for the help, guys ._.